# Is it possible to get Epiphany to scroll by dragging the page (i.e. with a touch event)?

Tags: multi-touch, epiphany

Currently, Epiphany highlights text when you drag your finger over it on a touch screen. Is it possible to get it to scroll instead of highlighting text? I feel like on a touch screen device, the expected behavior is to scroll the screen rather than to highlight text.